# using static constants -- A memory halt?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios

When we define a variable with following syntax does that mean it is hanging in the memory all the time:

```
static NSString *const kMyLabel = @"myLabel";
```

I have 100 of constants. Should I go with this of #define pre-processor compiler considering that #define will not keep them alive in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no difference between a constant static variable and #define directive. When using #define, the preprocessor will replace the variable with @"myLabel" every time it is used. This could mean that you have one instance of the string for each use, but the compiler combines them so that any strings in the binary are unique. Using the constant static, the code will load the location of the variable when needed. This means #define may be a tiny bit faster as there is less dereferencing to get the string, but it would be unnoticeable.

Comment: Not *quite* true. If the constant string is from another binary, you could reference it as an extern and have only one uniqued copy instead of one per binary.

Comment: @Catfish_Man True, but the definition in the question is static, so it can't be referenced externally unless a wrapper is made for it.

Comment: That isn't really true, @Catfish_Man.  Or, more explicitly, it is a function of link time optimizations.  In theory, the linker would uniquify all strings across the link unit and there'd be only one copy.  A similar optimization could be done via the dyld shared cache.  In practice, I'm not sure where the lines are drawn.

Comment: Hm, yeah? I have been misled then. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 3):

Hardcoded strings, in the format `@"my string"`, are baked into the application binary.  In order to make it *not* be permanent, you'd have to do:

```
static NSString *kMyLabel = nil;

...somewhere else
kMyLabel = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"myLabel"];
```

But that'd be stupid, because then you'd have both `@"myLabel"` in memory (because it's part of the app binary) AND your allocated string.  So double the memory.

In short:

If you have a constant string, there's no way to "unload" it from memory.  And unless you're hard coding a few chapters from a book into your binary, it's not going to be something to worry about.  Have you measured it as being a performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

It will be "in memory", but it will just be a memory mapped section of your application's executable file. If there's memory pressure, that page will be flushed without writing to disk.

Basically, it's "free" except for a tiny bit of IO on startup. Go nuts with them.